# Multiple Data Sources and Autowired JDBC Template Causes Bad SQL Grammar in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am working with an existing Spring Boot application.  The application.properties file specifies a "`spring.datasource`" database.  Through the magic of Spring, this data source was used by the following NamedParameterJdbcTemplate throughout the code:

```
@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;
```

I need to access additional data sources.  I added the database properties to the application.properties file.  Then I modified the Configure.java file to look like this:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSource")  
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}   

@Bean(name = "namedJdbcTemplate")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Bean(name = "dbiSupportDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.dbisupport")
public DataSource dbiSupportDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

I kept the auto wiring to the `namedJdbcTemplate` and added auto wiring to my new data source:

```
@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
DataSource dbiSupportDataSource;
```

With this code, a SQL query to the new database source results in errors like this:

> bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM `support.core`.table]

If I comment out the original data source and `namedJdbcTemplate` from the Configure.java file, the same SQL query works successfully.

I will also note that a SQL query to `namedJdbcTemplate` continues to work successfully even if I add a new data source.

Did I do something wrong when setting up my new data source?  Do I need to change my SQL query to the new data source?

Answer (score 1):

SQL queries started working to both databases once I defined templates for all data sources in the Configuration file.  In other words, I added the following to Configuration.java:

```
@Bean(name = "dbiSupportJdbc")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate dbiSupportJdbc(
        @Qualifier("dbiSupportDataSource") DataSource dbiSupportDataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dbiSupportDataSource);
}
```

Then I autowired both templates rather than mixing templates and data sources:

```
@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate dbiSupportJdbc;
```